# srReader.GetValue(1) using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vb6, vbscript

I am very New to Vb.net.

We are using fortify software for projects when it is going to LIVE. In that process I got some cross-Site Scripting : persistent Data flow issues.

Can anybody know how to resolve the following issue:

```
CType(srReader.GetValue(1), String)

CType(srReader.GetValue(2), String)
```

When I am loading the above value into some labels it is showing error; error name as mentioned above.

guys can anybody knows how to get this value in a different way.

Comment: If srReader is a DBReader, then GetValue(1) is probably DBNull which you can't cast directly.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to inspect the value of `srReader.GetValue(1)`(set a breakpoint in  that line and use the quick-watch-window)? What error do you get? You know that `GetValue` needs the index(**zero-based** column ordinal) of the field?! Hence you get the first field by `srReader.GetValue(0)`.

Comment: It is working fine with the above code, but we need to modify the code  according to FORTIFY SOFTWARE in Visual Studio. can you please let me know is there any other way to get the value.

Comment: what is srReader? You need to post some more code and more explanation of what the actual issue is.

Comment: And what would be according to FORTIFY SOFTWARE!?

Comment: Matt : SrReader is SqlDataReader

Comment: Alex: It is a security analysis Tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more context around where you are using this type cast? I don't know what fortify software is, but if it is a security analysis tool and you are receiving "Cross site scripting" errors, then the problem is most likely that you are returning this string in it's native state to be rendered as HTML. To avoid cross-site scripting risks, you should be html-encoding this value. That is, unless it is known to be safe and intended to be rendered as HTMl, in which case you'll just have to ignore or suppress this error.

Comment: This is Actual code which i am using : Select Case objGlobal.getDataSet(queryString, srReader)
                Case False
                    hidMessage.Value = CType(clsGlobal.errMsg, String)
                    loadData = False

Comment: Case Else
                    While srReader.Read
                        strsysname = srReader.GetValue(1)
                        lblSystemName.Text = CType(strsysname, String)
                        lblHeatID.Text = CType(srReader.GetValue(2), String)
                        lblCMReference.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(3) = "", "-", srReader.GetValue(3)), String)

Comment: Label1.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(4) = "", "-", srReader.GetValue(4)), String)
                        lblCMPurpose.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(5) = "", "-", clsGlobal.applyStringSetting(CType(srReader.GetValue(5), String))), String)
                        Label2.Text = CType(srReader.GetValue(6), String)
                        Label3.Text = CType(srReader.GetValue(7), String)
                        Label4.Text = CType(srReader.GetValue(8), String)
                        Label5.Text = CType(srReader.GetValue(9), String)

Comment: lblB_remarks.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(17) = "", "-", clsGlobal.applyStringSetting(CType(srReader.GetValue(17), String))), String)
                        lblC_remarks.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(18) = "", "-", clsGlobal.applyStringSetting(CType(srReader.GetValue(18), String))), String)
                        lblD_remarks.Text = CType(IIf(srReader.GetValue(19) = "", "-", clsGlobal.applyStringSetting(CType(srReader.GetValue(19), String))), String)

Comment: queryString = CType(("SELECT STATUSDESCRIPTION FROM TBLSTATUS WHERE STATUSID = '" & srReader.GetValue(24) & "' "), String)
                        'lblMessage.Text = "Incident Report Status : " & objGlobal.getDataString(queryString)
                        lblIRStatus.Text = objGlobal.getDataString(queryString)
                        If srReader.GetValue(25) <> Session("employeeID") Then
                            btnEdit.Visible = False
                        End If

Comment: From the above code i need to get the System name, userid and other values need to capture from srreader. but the Security tool showing bad code. IS there any other way to get the value using sqladpater in vb.net

Comment: It is hard to read your code samples in comments, but it appears that you are writing the output of the sql statement directly to the label text. This can open you up to Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Recommendation would be to HtmlEncode the values using the AntiXSS library:

http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample example for it.

Comment: I tried above way like i used the AntiXSS library, even though it is showing cross site scripting error. But it is just transferred from Critical error to medium level. Suggest me, if i am wrong or missing anything. i added the following code :

Comment: imports Microsoft.Security.Application  Encoder.HtmlEncode(CType(srReader.GetValue(1), String)) with refernce to antixss.dll